# Peach tree bark splitting and Brown rot prevention

Tags: rot, peaches, protection

My peach tree(s) which are about 5 years old, started developed "whitish" growth on the stem over the last two years. Great to hear some opinion on

1. How to prevent and avoid issue spreading and maintain a healthy tree

[image: Peach_Trunk_Image1_Whitish_growth]

[image: Peach_Trunk_Image2_Whitish_growth]

Tree Bark Splitting

[image: Peach_Trunk_Image3_Bark_Splitting]

2) How to prevent brown rot on the fruit - This happened for even fruits that were fine when harvested and subsequently developed brown rot on storage. What are some management techniques during off-season.

[image: Peach_Brownrot]

Fruits rotting on the tree itself

[image: Peach_Brownrot]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://sfyl.ifas.ufl.edu/media/sfylifasufledu/lake/docs/fruit-production/pdf/Peach-Diseases-2018.pdf) is everything you should ever want to know about peach diseases, including how to treat your (well, your peaches') brown rot. The first course of treatment is to religiously remove all rotted/dried fruits from your tree and the ground under the tree. This white paper also has some fungicide information.

The white patches on the bark are called lenticels and are normal and nothing to worry about. Many trees get them, especially members of the Prunus genus (such as cherries, plums, and peaches).

Answer (score 0):

And; peaches are a short lived tree , lose some branches normally, and need pruning for maximum production .I would think more in terms of where I would plant a replacement tree that would be bearing fruit is a few years when your present tree is gone. You do not store fresh peaches , if you do not eat them , you freeze or can them.